# GC Compute Engine: Unable to Access VM's

Tags: cloud, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

The Default startup scripts are not installed automatically, so it gives an error.
The error displayed is: **"The connection was denied because the user account is not authorized for remote login"**

```
Calling oobe-script from metadata.
attributes/sysprep-oobe-script-bat value is not set or metadata server is not reachable.
attributes/sysprep-oobe-script-cmd value is not set or metadata server is not reachable.
attributes/sysprep-oobe-script-ps1 value is not set or metadata server is not reachable.
Running schtasks with arguments /run /tn GCEStartup
--> SUCCESS: Attempted to run the scheduled task "GCEStartup".
-------------------------------------------------------------
Instance setup finished. palids is ready to use.
-------------------------------------------------------------
Booting on date 02/14/2015 15:34:18 
attributes/windows-startup-script-bat value is not set or metadata server is not reachable.
attributes/windows-startup-script-cmd value is not set or metadata server is not reachable.
attributes/windows-startup-script-ps1 value is not set or metadata server is not reachable.
```

I tried some commands but no luck. How do I overcome this?

Comment: Where do you get the error "The connection was denied because the user account is not authorized for remote login" ? Is it when trying to RDP to the instance ? the errors you are seeing indicate that there is no custom startup script in metadata and you can ignore those. You may want to try the initial user and password that were set on creation, which you can get by running $ gcloud compute instances describe palids

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Marius points out, that serial console output is to be expected. Two considerations:

1 - your initial **username** must be different than the hostname / VM name, and;

2 - the **password** chosen during VM creation must meet password complexity requirements:

- Have at least 8 characters.
- Follow these additional [complexity requirements](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc786468(v=ws.10).aspx).
- Cannot contain any non-ASCII characters, which are not supported.

Comprehensive Windows on GCE documentation can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/operating-systems/windows#rdp-console). Also consider that Windows VMs usually require 10 min approx before they are fully usable, as described in the [Windows on GCE documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/operating-systems/windows#rdp-console).

Comment: Thank you for this, I was 16 at the time, really glad that people like you who help me grow and learn :)